# How to suppress SA and CS erro codes in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, stylecop

I have problem with Suppression state of warnings thrown by StyleCop.Analyzer.

I am trying to start using it, but i have a lot of warnings, that I need suppress first. All of the warnings have Suppression State as N/A and I am not able to suppress that in file. Is here any way how to suppress them?

The same problem is with Microsoft.AnalyzerPowerpack.

Comment: You could just fix them. If you need help with a *specific* one, please post it. Right now it's hard to tell why you cannot do what you want to do.

Comment: On a sidenote: I'd suggest you don't suppress anything that you want to fix later. It's easy to suppress it first and forget about it. Don't invalidate your tool from the start by suppressing it's output.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. The problem is, that we start to manage older project with new team. So I want them to follow rules. There are about 30k warnings (mostly XML comments), that would take long to fix. I need to suppress that, but keep the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Settings.StyleCop to the legacy projects and disable the errors or disable all error checking for said projects

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

You could misappropriate auto-generated in the offending files: (with the appropriate comment explaining why of course)

```
// <auto-generated />
```